# Android emulator version upgrade

Tags: android

This is the error i got trying to use android emulator

```
INFO | Android emulator version 32.1.15.0 (build_id 10696886) (CL:N/A) 
INFO | Found systemPath /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-34/google_apis/x86_64/ 
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): SupportPixelFold 
ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD 
ERROR | is an experimental feature. 
ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. 
INFO | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-user/emu-crash.db, detection is enabled 
INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
```

Comment: Please don't remove line breaks when pasting text into your question. That makes reading extreme hard.